# Do I still need mortar under this drop-in tub?

Tags: bathroom, bathtub, mortar

I managed putting it in and all the wood frame. Now I'm feeling a bit lazy for the mortar works under the tub. Also this tub comes with support at its bottom and I saw online for similar tubs, mortar base is not needed. But I'm first time DIYer so please kindly share with me your thoughts. T

This is an American Standard 2422V002.020 Evolution Deep Soak. The manual says for 2422V/L:

> Replace whirlpool and re-shim the integral support feet, shimming the entire length of the support feet. Secure the shims using construction adhesive, silicone, mortar or equivalent materials. While not a necessity, the use of a foundation base consisting of cement, mortar, or grout will help provide a solid and secure installation

[image]

Comment: What to the installation instructions for the tub suggest?  That tub will weigh a lot when filled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears to be some sort of plastic/fiberglass tub. If you don't bed them, they move (which feels "cheap" when you stand in it, because it is) and the movement leads to fatigue cracking, and the fatigue cracking leads to leaks.

It may take some time to reach that point, but it will get there, almost always.

Put the "mortar, cement or grout" under it as mentioned in the manual. It will feel solid when you use it, and it will not suffer fatigue cracking later on in life.

Comment: Looks to me like it has an integrated base.  The last tub I installed had a built-in wedge that was meant to sit flat on the floor—no mortar required.  Obviously, if your floor isn't flat you may need to do some leveling or shimming, but with such a tub a mortar bed isn't strictly necessary.

Comment: @Huesmann I see gaps. I trust filling them.

Comment: Hence "if your floor isn't flat you may need to do some leveling or shimming."  We're also assuming the front apron framing isn't too high, and that the tub isn't resting on it.